# How to migrate MySQL Master/Master replication to MySQL Galera Cluster?

Tags: mysql, galera

Currently our setup consists of two MySQL 5.6 servers on seperate Ubuntu 14.04 bare mettal machines. I am looking into migrating the system to a MySQL Galera Cluster on 3 nodes.

Can I "patch" the current MySQL instance with the Galera 3 wsrep provider, or would I need to deinstall the MySQL instance entirely before installing a MySQL Galera instance? What is the recommended migrating process?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do NOT patch your MySQL binaries any more. But you also do NOT have to de-install the instance. You just have to replace the MySQL Binaries with the Galera-MySQL Binaries and install the Galera Plug-in.

You best do this with the Galera Repository for Ubuntu:

http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/installmysql.html

For the further migration process from Master/Master to Galera you can look at the suggestions here:

http://fromdual.com/migrating-from-mysql-master-master-to-galera-replication

Comment: So I simply leave the working mysql installation and configuration and data where it is and install the galera binaries? Is there any negative inpact / drawback on this procedure?